# Kubernetes pod in crashloopbackoff

Tags: docker, kubernetes, service, deployment, crashloopbackoff

I am new to Kubernetes.

Following is the yaml I am running:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
    app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  name: k8-demo-aishwarya
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
    app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
    app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  name: k8-demo-aishwarya
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
      app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
        app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: docker.io/aishvaryaps/spring-boot-on-kubernetes-example:0.12-SNAPSHOT
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: k8-demo-aishwarya
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

---

Getting a crashloopbackoff error

Can anyone guide me?

No issue with the image, it runs properly, I have tested that on Docker.

**Kubernetes pod logs are as follows**:

```
1. Successfully assigned default/k8-demo-aishwarya-fdd8d58c6-lvxp9 to gke-cluster-3-pool-1-997819b9-j3b2
2. Container image "docker.io/aishvaryaps/spring-boot-on-kubernetes-example:0.12-SNAPSHOT" already present on machine
3. Created container k8-demo-aishwarya
4. Started container k8-demo-aishwarya
5. Back-off restarting failed container
```

Comment: What does happen when you run that image on plain Docker?  Do you have the `kubectl logs` of the failing pod?

Comment: Preferably `kubectl logs --previous` to make sure that all container logs before exiting will be collected :)

Comment: `kubectl logs default/k8-demo-aishwarya-fdd8d58c6-lvxp9` output please. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the logs of POD for more details however i think it's due to processing is ending inside container and printing `Hello World by Aishwarya S!` you can check same by logs.

You can keep running pod by adding line in your YAML :

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 1000"]
```

This command keep pod running

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
    app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  name: k8-demo-aishwarya
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
      app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: k8-demo-aishwarya
        app.kubernetes.io/version: version1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        image: docker.io/aishvaryaps/spring-boot-on-kubernetes-example:0.12-SNAPSHOT
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec", "sleep 1000"]
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: k8-demo-aishwarya
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 1):

The container is running and is printing the hello world message and exiting. See below the logs from container.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
2b177abdbae1        aishvaryaps/spring-boot-on-kubernetes-example:0.12-SNAPSHOT   "/bin/sh -c 'java ${…"   12 seconds ago      Exited (0) 10 seconds ago                       dummy


$ docker logs -f 2b1
Hello World by Aishwarya S!
```

If you want to keep the container running, the process inside the container should continue to run. You might need to print the message from a while or for loop.